# vba : IS THERE ANY WAY TO GET COUNT OF ROWS REMOVED? AFTER APPLYING REMOVE DUPLICATES(SINGLE/MULTIPLE)

Tags: excel, vba

HERE MY DOUBT IS :**In VBA Coding, Is there any possible to know** ,
How many rows are affected after running the below procedure

```
Sub RemoveDuplicatesWithNoHeaders()
Range("A1:D35").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo ' for mutiple columns Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
End Sub
```

AFTER THIS PROCEDURE RUN ,CAN WE GET HOW MANY ROWS ARE REMOVED

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when posting.

Comment: sorry as it is not accepting please and all ,I just posted my question directly without formal format ,next time I will check my question

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: OK when I tried to put my previous answer into a function, it did not work, so clearly my testing was faulty...

Here's an alternative which should actually work (by counting the number of blank cells in the range pre- and post-duplicate removal)

```
Sub TestDupsCount()

    Debug.Print RemoveAndCountDuplicates(Range("A1").CurrentRegion, _
                                         Array(1, 2, 3, 4), xlNo)

End Sub

Function RemoveAndCountDuplicates(rng As Range, ArrCols, _
                                  haveHeaders As XlYesNoGuess)
    Dim oldBlank As Long, newBlank As Long, rv
    rv = 0
    oldBlank = NumEmptyRows(rng)
    'https://stackoverflow.com/question/39104653/vba-remove-duplicates-fails-when-columns-array-is-passed-using-a-variable
    rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(ArrCols), Header:=haveHeaders
    newBlank = NumEmptyRows(rng)
    RemoveAndCountDuplicates = newBlank - oldBlank
End Function
Function NumEmptyRows(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim rw As Range, i As Long, cols As Long
    cols = rng.Columns.Count
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        If Application.CountBlank(rw) = cols Then i = i + 1
    Next rw
    NumEmptyRows = i
End Function
```

Comment: thanks for your replay, here after running the above code getting count "0" and we are hard coding the c value ''''''''' wsDest.Range("A1" & ":" & Cells(LastRow1, LastCol1).Address).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(darray), Header:=xlYes '''''' While giving range dynamically how to achieve that logic

Comment: Sorry - my previous reply was faulty.  Working solution above.